# PyQt - How to set QComboBox in a table view using QItemDelegate

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am trying to display a combo box in my table, so that I can set the selected index from the table model, as with the other cells in the table. I have pieced this together from other examples but still cannot understand how the interaction works to set the selected index of the QComboBox.

This is the simplest example I can come up with to demonstrate the problem. If anyone can demonstrate how to set the index automatically from model data? Also how to use the 'currentIndexChanged' signal, as this seems to fire almost continuously whenever it is repainted? Thanks.

```
# The following tells SIP (the system that binds Qt's C++ to Python)
# to return Python native types rather than QString and QVariant
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)


from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    """
    A simple 5x4 table model to demonstrate the delegates
    """
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): return 5
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): return 4

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid(): return None
        if not role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: return None
        return "{0:02d}".format(index.row())


class ComboDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    """
    A delegate that places a fully functioning QComboBox in every
    cell of the column to which it's applied
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):

        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self.parent())
        self.connect(self.combo, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), self.parent().currentIndexChanged)

        li = []
        li.append("Zero")
        li.append("One")
        li.append("Two")
        li.append("Three")
        li.append("Four")
        li.append("Five")

        self.combo.addItems(li)

        if not self.parent().indexWidget(index):
            self.parent().setIndexWidget(
                index, 
                self.combo
            )

class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    """
    A simple table to demonstrate the QComboBox delegate.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QTableView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Set the delegate for column 0 of our table
        # self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, ButtonDelegate(self))
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, ComboDelegate(self))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def currentIndexChanged(self, ind):
        print "Combo Index changed {0} {1} : {2}".format(ind, self.sender().currentIndex(), self.sender().currentText())

if __name__=="__main__":
    from sys import argv, exit

    class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
        """
        A simple test widget to contain and own the model and table.
        """
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

            l=QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
            self._tm=TableModel(self)
            self._tv=TableView(self)
            self._tv.setModel(self._tm)
            l.addWidget(self._tv)

    a=QtGui.QApplication(argv)
    w=Widget()
    w.show()
    w.raise_()
    exit(a.exec_())
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're using `paint` method incorrectly. It should be used when you want to change displaying behavior of the view. Also creating new widget each time you want to paint it is very expensive. But you want to change editing behavior so you need to change entire logic of your program.

See the [fixed code](https://gist.github.com/Riateche/5984815). Below I'll expain the changes.

`1.` First of all, we need to make the first column editable. You can do it by reimplementing `QAbstractItemModel::flags`:

```
def flags(self, index):
    if (index.column() == 0):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
    else:
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
```

`2.` By default the item editor is created when user performs a double click on item. If you want to show all comboboxes by default, you can use `openPersistentEditor`:

```
for row in range(0, self._tm.rowCount()):
    self._tv.openPersistentEditor(self._tm.index(row, 0))
```

Note that you should also open editors for newly created cells (if any).

`3.` Now back to our delegate. We need to implement `createEditor` method that will be automatically called by the view when an editor is requested for a cell:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    combo = QtGui.QComboBox(parent)
    li = []
    li.append("Zero")
    li.append("One")
    li.append("Two")
    li.append("Three")
    li.append("Four")
    li.append("Five")
    combo.addItems(li)
    self.connect(combo, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), 
                 self, QtCore.SLOT("currentIndexChanged()"))
    return combo
```

Note that `connect` is below `append`s because we need to avoid `currentIndexChanged` signals on initialization.

`4.` Implement `setEditorData` method that will be called by the view when model data has been changed. Also it will be called once when an editor is initialized.

```
def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
    editor.blockSignals(True)
    editor.setCurrentIndex(int(index.model().data(index)))
    editor.blockSignals(False)
```

Again, we want to avoid signals that are not caused by the user, so we use `blockSignals`.

`5.` In the slot we simply emit `commitData` signal that will cause the view to call the `setModelData` of our delegate:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def currentIndexChanged(self):
    self.commitData.emit(self.sender())
```

`6.` Implement `setModelData` method:

```
def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
    model.setData(index, editor.currentIndex())
```

`7.` Your model needs to support data changing. So we should implement `setData` method of the model:

```
def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    print "setData", index.row(), index.column(), value
    # todo: remember the data
```

Comment: I have added a follow up question about the data model [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697352/pyqt-implement-a-qabstracttablemodel-for-display-in-qtableview) rather than extending this question too much.

Comment: Also another follow up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748546/pyqt-column-of-checkboxes-in-a-qtableview) regarding adding a column of checkboxes to the view.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but I have trouble implementing your solution. I have posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945016/pyqt-qcombobox-in-qtableview).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! In terms of calling `openPersistentEditor()`, what one can do instead of looping is calling it in the `paint()` function of the delegate.