# How to add QTreeView in a QTableView column

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview

I am fairly new to PyQt, I'm working on a project that contains a QTableView, with one of its columns displaying system paths. I would like to add a QTreeView so users can click the **+** or **>** buttons to expand what is underneath the paths.

Here is my basic implementation:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(600,400)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Basic Treeview")

        self.treeview = QtGui.QTreeView(self)

        self.treeview.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.treeview.model.setRootPath('/opt')
        self.treeview.setModel(self.treeview.model)
        self.treeview.setColumnWidth(0, 200)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.treeview)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Although, in the above case, I get all folders but I just want the `/opt` path and its underneath folders.

```
import operator
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data_list, header, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        # setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 570, 450)
        self.setWindowTitle("Click on column title to sort")
        table_model = MyTableModel(self, data_list, header)
        table_view = QTableView()
        table_view.setModel(table_model)
        # set font
        font = QFont("Courier New", 14)
        table_view.setFont(font)
        # set column width to fit contents (set font first!)
        table_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        # enable sorting
        table_view.setSortingEnabled(True)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(table_view)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent, mylist, header, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.mylist = mylist
        self.header = header

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.mylist)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.mylist[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return self.mylist[index.row()][index.column()]

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.header[col]
        return None

# the solvent data ...
header = ['Name', ' Email', ' Status', ' Path']
# use numbers for numeric data to sort properly
data_list = [
('option_A', 'zyro@email.com', 'Not Copied', '/Opt'),
('option_B', 'zyro@email.com', 'Not Copied', '/Users'),
]
app = QApplication([])
win = MyWindow(data_list, header)
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Visual example :

[image]

Comment: Just letting you know that I've completed the second par of my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your question can be divided in two parts:

1. how, in a *QTreeView*, the `/opt` path and its children can be shown, but without showing its siblings. In other words, how is it possible to show the root directory in a *QTreeView* ;
2. how can a *QTreeView* be added to a *QTableView*.

## 1. How to include the root directory in a QTreeView :

The root of a *QTreeView* is the directory for which the content is shown in the view. It is set when calling the method `setRootIndex`. According to a [post by wysota on Qt Centre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/38120-QTreeWidget-How-to-display-the-root-item?p=175113#post175113):

> You can't display the invisibleRootItem because it is a fake item used only to have an equivalent of empty QModelIndex.

A workaround would be to set the root directory to the parent of `/opt` and filtering out the siblings of `/opt` with a subclass of a *QSortFilterProxyModel*. Note that I've also reimplemented the `sizeHint` method which will be necessary for the resizing of the rows of the *QTableView*:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os

class MyQTreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, path, parent=None):
        super(MyQTreeView, self).__init__(parent)

        ppath = os.path.dirname(path) # parent of path
        self.setFrameStyle(0)

        #---- File System Model ----

        sourceModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        sourceModel.setRootPath(ppath)

        #---- Filter Proxy Model ----

        proxyModel = MyQSortFilterProxyModel(path)
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(sourceModel)

        #---- Filter Proxy Model ----

        self.setModel(proxyModel)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setRootIndex(proxyModel.mapFromSource(sourceModel.index(ppath)))  

        #--- Hide All Header Sections Except First ----

        header = self.header()
        for sec in range(1, header.count()):
            header.setSectionHidden(sec, True)

    def sizeHint(self):
        baseSize = super(MyQTreeView,self).sizeHint()

        #---- get model index of "path" ----
        qindx = self.rootIndex().child(0, 0)

        if self.isExpanded(qindx): # default baseSize height will be used
            pass

        else:  # shrink baseShize height to the height of the row           
            baseSize.setHeight(self.rowHeight(qindx))

        return baseSize


class MyQSortFilterProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):    
    def __init__(self, path, parent=None):
        super(MyQSortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.path = path

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):

        model = self.sourceModel()
        path_dta = model.index(self.path).data()
        ppath_dta = model.index(os.path.dirname(self.path)).data()

        if parent.data() == ppath_dta:
            if parent.child(row, 0).data() == path_dta:                
                return True
            else:
                return False            
        else:
            return True
```

### 2. How to add a *QTreeView* to a *QTableView* :

It is possible to add a *QTreeView* to a *QTableView* by using a  *QItemDelegate*. The [post by Pavel Strakhov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615997/pyqt-how-to-set-qcombobox-in-a-table-view-using-qitemdelegate/17617147#17617147) greatly helped me for this, since I had never used *QTableView* in combination with delegates before answering to this question. I always used *QTableWidget* instead with the `setCellWidget` method.

Note that I've setup a signal in the *MyDelegate* class which call the method `resizeRowsToContents` in the *MyTableView* class. This way, the height of the rows resize according the the reimplementation of the `sizeHint` method of the *MyQTreeView* class.

```
class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent, mylist, header, *args):
        super(MyTableModel, self).__init__(parent, *args)
        self.mylist = mylist
        self.header = header

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.mylist)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.mylist[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        elif role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return self.mylist[index.row()][index.column()]

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.header[col]
        return None

class MyDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):

    treeViewHeightChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QWidget)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):

        editor = MyQTreeView(index.data(), parent)
        editor.collapsed.connect(self.sizeChanged)
        editor.expanded.connect(self.sizeChanged)

        return editor

    def sizeChanged(self):
        self.treeViewHeightChanged.emit(self.sender())

class MyTableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, data_list, header, *args):
        super(MyTableView, self).__init__(*args)

        #---- set up model ----

        model = MyTableModel(self, data_list, header)
        self.setModel(model)

        #---- set up delegate in last column ----

        delegate = MyDelegate()

        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, delegate)
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            self.openPersistentEditor(model.index(row, 3))

        #---- set up font and resize calls ----

        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Courier New", 14))
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        delegate.treeViewHeightChanged.connect(self.resizeRowsToContents)
```

### 3. Basic application :

Here is a basic application based on the code you provided in your OP:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    header = ['Name', ' Email', ' Status', ' Path']
    data_list = [('option_A', 'zyro@email.com', 'Not Copied', '/opt'),
                 ('option_B', 'zyro@email.com', 'Not Copied', '/usr')]

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MyTableView(data_list, header)
    win.setGeometry(300, 200, 570, 450)
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jean for your efforts are much appreciated, i hope this post is also useful for other learners .

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz You are quite welcomed. I've learned a lot in the process also, so its a win-win scenario. I'm glad if it can help others as well.